# Is there a reason why std::priority_queue as MinHeap requires greater than comparer; MaxHeap, less than comparer?

Tags: c++, stl, std, priority-queue

When I use std::priority_queue as a Min Heap for example, I'd need to do something like this:

```
struct MyType{
   ...
   int data;
};

auto greaterThanCmp = [](const MyType& a, const MyType& b){ return a > b; };

std::priority_queue<MyType, std::vector<MyType>, greaterThanCmp> minHeap;
```

My question is: is there an advantage to providing the greaterThanCmp for a Min Heap or would a less than comparer works just as well, had the committee/implementer gone that route.

Or in other words, why did the standard choose one over the other?

I have tried implementing my MinHeap class with a lessThanCmp just for the heck of it.  I tested my code, it works fine.

Thank you very much for your response in advance!

Comment: *"why did the standard choose one over the other?"* -- because they could not choose both? I suppose you really mean to ask why they specifically chose `std::less` over `std::greater`? Also, are you looking at `priority_queue` in isolation, or would you include the other ordered containers (like `std::set`) in your question?

Comment: `comparator` function simply decides the order of the elements. `greaterThan` would allow the smallest element to appear first, whereas `lessThan` allows the largest one to appear first. Standard chose `std::less` to be default one.

Comment: I'm guessing there's no particular reason to that.  It's probably just that most standard functions use `less` as the default comparator, and larger values "usually" have more `priority`.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a `greater` object, you can easily make a `less` object out of it:
`less ::operator() (a, b) { return greater (b, a) }`.  So the `less` requirement is not limiting.